# Mesclar comandos linux - rm e diff

Tags: linux, terminal

Estou aprendendo a usar o Linux com a IDE OpenSuse versão 13.1.

Gostaria de saber se é possível mesclar os comando `rm -r` com `diff - r`?

#### Objetivo

Remover os arquivos `1.txt`,`2.txt`,`2.txt` da `path1`, pois não possui na `path2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode-se usar direto o comando `rsync`, exemplo:

Para utilizar o *path2* como "modelo":

```
rsync -r --delete path2/ path1
```

**Importante**: A barra `/` é importante para copiar o conteúdo do diretório e o próprio diretório.

:)

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você possa utilizar o comando `xargs`. Dê uma olhada no [manual](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs) para detalhes.

Seria algo do tipo (não exatamente):

```
diff -r path1 path2 | xargs rm
```

A saída do `diff` tem algumas palavras a mais que não os nomes dos arquivos (*Only in path1:*, por exemplo), então talvez seja necessário tratar com uma expressão regular.